# Angular 2 Firebase Update Deployment

Tags: angular, firebase

I've create the default project using AngularCLI and deployed it to firebase by following this tutorial: https://coryrylan.com/blog/deploy-angular-2-cli-apps-to-firebase

I've updated the project from the default app works! to Hello World! to be displayed but when I run firebase deploy and view the project it still has the app works! being displayed.

So when I run the following commands the output is the following:

ng serve = Hello World!

firebase serve = app works!

firebase deploy = app works!

How do i go about deploying my changes to firebase?

Comment: Figured out my problem I wasn't running the command  ng build --prod before deploying